# Webpack not generating build.js

Tags: node.js, docker, webpack, docker-compose, webpack-2

I moved my codebase to a dockerformat.

I have a docker-compose file with the command:
`command: bash -c "rm -rf node_modules && npm install && npm run dev"`

and everything works fine, I use `rm -rf node_modules` because it gives me some errors of missing packages (from my MAC). Doing that it just gets recreated and it works ok on localhost.

I've also added volumes, so when I change something in my code it gets reflected in my container, this also works fine (apart of the hot-reload, but that's not a big deal).

Now I usually just comment out the line: `command: bash -c "rm -rf node_modules && npm install && npm run dev"` on my docker-compose file and instead I add:
`command: bash -c "rm -rf node_modules && npm install && npm run build"` to build my bundle, so that in production I don't have node at all, however this gives me no results.

I'm not sure if it's a problem with volumes, i.e. it gets built in the container but I can't access it from my machine (which I don't think because changing code in my local machine does get reflected in my container) or it doesn't get built at all for some reason.

This is the output of `command: bash -c "rm -rf node_modules && npm install && npm run build --verbose"`

```
NODE     | npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules/fsevents):
NODE     | npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
NODE     | 
NODE     | added 115 packages in 11.036s
NODE     | npm info it worked if it ends with ok
NODE     | npm verb cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node',
NODE     | npm verb cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
NODE     | npm verb cli   'run',
NODE     | npm verb cli   'build',
NODE     | npm verb cli   '--verbose' ]
NODE     | npm info using npm@5.5.1
NODE     | npm info using node@v9.2.0
NODE     | npm verb run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
NODE     | npm info lifecycle frontend@1.0.0~prebuild: frontend@1.0.0
NODE     | npm info lifecycle frontend@1.0.0~build: frontend@1.0.0
NODE     | 
NODE     | > frontend@1.0.0 build /code/client
NODE     | > cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules
NODE     | 
NODE     | Hash: cda5e46c2c7f4ba2903b                                                              
NODE     | Version: webpack 3.9.1
NODE     | Time: 27298ms
NODE     |        Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
NODE     |     build.js  1.29 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
NODE     | build.js.map  7.65 MB       0  [emitted]         main
NODE     | npm verb lifecycle frontend@1.0.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
NODE     | npm verb lifecycle frontend@1.0.0~build: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/code/client/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
NODE     | npm verb lifecycle frontend@1.0.0~build: CWD: /code/client
NODE     | npm info lifecycle frontend@1.0.0~postbuild: frontend@1.0.0
NODE     | npm verb exit [ 0, true ]
NODE     | npm info ok
```

And my webpack conf file starts like this:

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack') 

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../static/dist/'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
```

Which at least before worked fine since my app looks like this:

```
- manage.py
- static
  - dist
  - others
- client
  - webpack.config.js
```

etc

Why nothing gets build in dist?

#### Update

I used exec to look inside the container. I can't find the build.js anywhere. I also run touch abc.txt inside /code/static/dist and it gets also created on my localhost, i.e. the volumes work fine.It must be a problem of webpack and not docker.

#### Update 2

I've also tried the full path like this, still nothing:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '/code/static/dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
```

#### Edit 3

I've tried to look for build.js I found these files, but I think that those are not my build.js:

```
root@0xxxxxx:/code# find . -name build.js
./client/node_modules/node-forge/nodejs/build.js
./client/node_modules/errno/build.js
./client/node_modules/vue-template-compiler/build.js
./client/node_modules/builtin-status-codes/build.js
./client/node_modules/webpack-dev-middleware/node_modules/mime/src/build.js
./client/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js
./client/node_modules/node-sass/scripts/build.js
./client/node_modules/mime/build/build.js
./client/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js
./client/node_modules/npm/node_modules/sorted-union-stream/node_modules/from2/node_modules/readable-stream/node_modules/isarray/build/build.js
./client/node_modules/npm/lib/install/action/build.js
./client/node_modules/npm/lib/build.js
```

Comment: Please post your Dockerfile and how you are running it.

Comment: I've solved the error, thanks @TJBiddle

Answer (score 3):

Your path is wrong. You build your `build.js` file out of your project directory.

Just change to this:

`path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'static/dist')`

Comment: @Costantin could you give me please the latest version of webpack.config.js and app structure? I will try on my local.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to solve this. I was trying hundreds of things, so I'm not entirely sure if this made the trick, but creating a new file and posting my docker-compose on it made it work. I think its possibly related to file permissions. Check those if you get this error.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing var path declaration. But webpack should be crushing without it, so not sure if that's the reason.

```
var path = require('path');
```

Comment: ahh so sorry, I thought they were common on webpack. I do have on top:
`var path = require('path')`
`var webpack = require('webpack')`
Still nothing, any idea what it could be?

Comment: Try to `docker exec` into the container an see if it gets biult.

Comment: Hi @AndrijaĆeranić I tried, I can't find the `build.js` anywhere. I also run `touch abc.txt` inside `/code/static/dist` and it gets also created on my localhost, i.e. the volumes work fine. What else could it be?

Answer (score 2):

Try removing `/dist/` from path. It works on my machine.

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/main.js',
    output: {
       path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../static'),
       publicPath: '/dist/',
       filename: 'build.js'
    },
```